# Comparison of models by parameters from the database and form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I encountered such a problem. on the client, the user fills out the registration form, I accept it on the backend (in json format). Next, I need to make a comparison. If a document by email parameter already exists in the database, then send an error; if there is no such document with such an email, then create a new document in the database.

There will be a piece of my route responsible for these actions

```
    router.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
      try {
           //Block for passport session
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        const username = users.push({
          id: Date.now().toString(),
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: hashedPassword
        })
        //End of block for passport session

        const candidate = await User.findOne(username.email)
        if(candidate)  {
          console.log('User have been already registered!')
          console.log(candidate)
        } else {
          const participant = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })
        await participant.save()
        }
         res.redirect('/login')
      } catch(e) {
        res.redirect('/register')
        console.log(e);
      }
```

If my user collection is empty, then a new document is created( for example:

```
{ inst: null,
  vk: null,
  _id: 5e10b72626f9107d861621c0,
  name: 'Ivan',
  email: 'w@w',
  password:
   '$2b$10$/2dDrTMCOXSZnaIgOgFEBuNKuU8mbRFKyV9.4U6brERsLpOVJoBAS',
  __v: 0 }
```

), but if at least one document exists, then it does not allow me to create a user(`User have been already registered!`). Apparently he checks in general for the existence of a document with email parameters, but I don’t know how to find the exact document with the email parameter that entered the user on the form on the client( `const candidate = await User.findOne(username.email`/* how to refer correctly to this parameter which the user drives into the form?.*/`))`

Comment: Please console.log of candidate value ?

Comment: means what response comes when called user query ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t quite understand what value you are interested in. If the user collection is empty, then the server allows me to create a user                            ```{ inst: null,
  vk: null,
  _id: 5e10b72626f9107d861621c0,
  name: 'Ivan',
  email: 'w@w',
  password:
   '$2b$10$/2dDrTMCOXSZnaIgOgFEBuNKuU8mbRFKyV9.4U6brERsLpOVJoBAS',
  __v: 0 }```. if I have at least one document in the database, then he writes to me: ```  User have been already registered!  ``` Or are you interested in how the user model is composed?

Comment: you got error when you save second time data ?

Comment: Form on the client? Post method

Comment: No, i dont have error. When I search for a user in the database, I don’t know how to call the parameter I’m looking for( const candidate = await User.findOne(username.email)), because I need a parameter that drives the user into the form (email), and he searches the database for a document, in principle, with an email field, and this exists then it will issue an error.

Comment: the server does not search by date that the user entered, it searches for the presence of at least one document with the email field

Comment: User.findOne({'email':username.email}) please use that code for find user

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Put your last comment in the answer box so that I can check your answer (as a solution that helped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 User.findOne({'email':username.email})
```